# Mobile Safari weird semi-transparent box

Tags: mobile, css, mobile-safari

Okay, so I've got a couple of headers with links in them. Like this:

```html
<h1><a href="">text</a></h1>
```

And then I rotate them using CSS3, like this:

```css
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-63px, -117.5px);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-63px, -117.5px);
```

I also use the translate prop. to position them where I want (rather than absolute positioning), for backwards compatibility purposes.

Now it looks perfect on Firefox or Chrome, but when I look at it on Mobile Safari it has these weird semi-transparent boxes going from the right of the container all the way off screen.

Any thoughts off hand? I can post examples if I have to, but before I do does anyone know what it could be? Thanks!

Comment: A bug in Mobile Safari, unable to properly render the transformation?  Have you set up a blank page with nothing but a rotation just to see if it still occurs?

Comment: Yup! As I found out, it was the text underline that was buggy. No clue why, but that was the problem. When I removed the text underline the problem was solved.

Comment: So it looks like the text rotates but the underline is left in its original position as a ghost in a box?  Definitely a Mobile Webkit rendering issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. For future reference, the problem was a bug in Mobile Safari. 
I had a 'text-decoration:underline;' on the link that I had rotated, and for some reason Safari stretched that out and made it partially transparent. No idea why it did this, but removing the text underline solved the problem. Thanks for your thoughts, everybody!

Comment: If your own answer works, you are free to accept it, as it solved your own problem.

Comment: @mc10, yes, the OP should remember to accept his own answer.  However, he is not allowed to do this for at least 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `-webkit-transform` and `-moz-transform` are browser-specific, and do not work with other browsers (i.e. Opera, IE, etc.). Reference: [CSS3 `transform` from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform). Safari for desktop should be working with `-webkit-transform`; the status on iOS Safari is unknown.

The following code should work on more browsers (i.e. it should be more portable):

```css
transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-63px, -117.5px);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-63px, -117.5px); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-63px, -117.5px);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-63px, -117.5px);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-63px, -117.5px);
```

Comment: Your answer seems like it fails to address the OP's issue.  If the CSS rule applies to Mobile Safari, then it should work fine.  If the CSS rule does not apply to Mobile Safari, then it should be ignored.  So what explains the weird outline he describes?

Comment: That depends on what other CSS styles the OP has on the page that are relevant to the element.

Comment: You clearly state, _"The problem is that..."_.  Yet, if it's being caused by something else on his page, then that's not the problem as identified by your answer.  In other words, we're talking about Mobile Safari and you're saying that CSS rules specifically targeting Desktop browsers are the problem.  How can that be?  Does Mobile Safari use Webkit rules?  If so, then it seems like a bug.

Comment: No, that wasn't the problem~ I have all of the prefixed versions, but I only included the two that were important to me explaining the problem. Thanks for the answer though!